# Adding a 2nd page to my React app, Unable to read .js file error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to add a 2nd page to my react app without installing any new plugins or making significant modifications.

I added `monsters.html` to my public directory and `monsters.js` to src, next to `index.js`. When I navigate to `localhost:3000/monsters.html`, I get this error:

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More]  monsters.js:1

monsters.js:, in src/ right next to `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react',
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

monsters.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>Monsters 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Foo</div>
    <div id="root2"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="../src/monsters.js"></script>
</html>

monsters.html, in public
```

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: First line is ending in `,` instead of `;`.
Depending on the loader you are using, you may need to specify the extension of local files: `import App from './App.jsx'`. It's a little confusing - is your file called `App.jsx` or `index.jsx`? If these aren't the problem, please update with information regarding your project & build setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply include a JSX syntax file as a script into your HTML, first you must transpile it into javascript (hence the syntax error about `<` syntax).

**The production solution**

You need to rename to `monsters.jsx`, and add some build config to get it output as expected.

Without info on your current build tool or config, I can only suggest that if using a webpack build you will need add it as another entry file (assuming you want separate bundle for each HTML page), set up output bundles to map to your entry files, and make sure you have a JSX transform rule (NOTE: this will output to `/dist/index.js` and `/dist/monsters.js` which will be the files you point to in your HTML script tags)...

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports ={
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    monsters: './src/monsters.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          options: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**The quick and dirty non-overwhelming solution**

Alternatively as a shortcut this can be done using babel standalone from the HTML file itself, although this is not the norm for building production react apps, it should work if only interested in playing with React and JSX. Heres a tutorial for that https://medium.com/@to_pe/how-to-add-react-to-a-simple-html-file-a11511c0235f (just remember to bump the versions of react, react-dom, and babel-standalone to the current ones)